# How to use SummarySaver (monitor) in TF contrib.learn.estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to know how to use 
[SummarySaver](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py#L559)
monitor with `contrib.learn.estimator`

I understand and used `ValidationMonitor` but I am struggling on

1. Understanding the use case for `SummarySaver`
2. Using it in conjunction with `contrib.learn.estimator`

As an aside, what is the best practice to add summaries that are not `metrics` defined in `ValidationMonitor` ?

Answer (score 1):

- SummarySaver is for writing summary out every n steps
- manual summary can be most easily done by using [tf.scalar_summary](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#scalar_summary)

Comment: That's fine, but I am looking for an example on how to use SummarySaver with Estimator.

Comment: Answer given by Martin Wicke from TensorFlow - 
SummarySaver can be used for the purpose of summarizing things from inside the model. To use it, make a summary (or merge several) and remember the name of the summary op. Then make a SummarySaver and pass it the name of the op. You don't need to provide the scaffold.

We're changing the model_fn return type on master right now, which will make this easier.